# Triggering build with properties via API

Tags: json, teamcity

I want to trigger a build on my TeamCity 10.0.3 server, using REST API.

The example is listed in XML-format, and is working in a test application:

```
<build>
    <buildType id="buildConfID"/>
    <properties>
        <property name="env.myEnv" value="bbb"/>
    </properties>
</build>
```

My API is using JSON instead:

```
{"buildType": {"id":"buildConfId"},
 "Properties":[
  {"Name":"myParameter","Value":"bbb"}
 ]
}
```

The build is triggered correctly, but the parameter is not set. What I found out the `Properties` field needs to be uppercase to be accepted by TeamCity.
I have no clue on how to format parameters so that they will be accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I found the source code for [Properties-class](http://svn.jetbrains.org/teamcity/plugins/rest-api/trunk/src/jetbrains/buildServer/server/rest/model/Properties.java). Properties need to be written lower-case, looks like I'm receiving OK-Response, because it wasn't parsed.

The correct call will look like:

```
{
 "buildType": {"id":"buildConfId"},
 "properties": {
  "property": [
    {"Name":"myParameter","Value":"bbb"}
   ]
  }
}
```